# Unable to increment char* pointer

Tags: c++

I'm a little rusty on pointers so bear with me. I have declared an array of chars and a char* pointer which is set in the following manner:

```
char* memPointer = &mem_arr[0];
```

When I run the program, it looks like my starting address is 6E2D200C (this address is always the same for some reason. I'm not sure if this is right or not. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong)
Then, at some point when the user requests some memory, I try to increment the pointer and print out the new address. But the address remains the same as mentioned above. Here is what i have tried with no success:

```
//*(memPointer += actualSize); //no change
//memPointer += actualSize; //no change
//*memPointer += actualSize;// no change
&memPointer += actualSize; //no change
```

actualSize is an int by the way. If there is any other information that I need to provide, please let me know. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How are you ascertaining that the pointer isn't incrementing? My hunch is you're doing the increment inside a function and testing it outside, and you're passing the pointer to the function by value, that's usually what brings people here claiming a pointer doesn't increment.

Comment: @kfsone I am checking it the line below the increment with: printf("memPointer address now = %p\n", &memPointer);

Comment: You're printing the address of memPointer rather than it's value?

Comment: A pointer is a variable that holds an address. When you say `int i = 10`, then `i` has a value of `10`. When you say `char* mem_pointer = &mem_arr[0]` then `mem_pointer` has the value of the address of the first element of mem_arr. `&mem_pointer` is the address of the pointer, not the contents of the pointer. `mem_pointer` is the address itself. So `memPointer += actualSize` is the correct way to increment it.

You would no more say "memPointer += actualSize; printf(... &memPointer);` than you would `i += 10; printf(..., &i);`

Comment: @kfsone I don't believe so. That print statement prints the address that I mentioned in the post. I use this for the value: printf("memPointer value = %s\n", memPointer); which prints out some test values I have from a strcpy. Or am I missing something? EDIT: Saw your second reply. I guess that makes sense. Still not sure what is going on with my prints then. It seems that if I try to print out the address, I get the value and vise versa. But I'll play around with it some more.

Comment: `printf(memPointer address now = %p\n", &memPointer);` prints the location in memory of memPointer, not the address value it contains. `&memPointer` evaluates to a pointer-to-memPointer, not memPointer itself. Remove the '&' from your printf and use `memPointer += actual_size`. See http://ideone.com/1gS2q4

Comment: @kfsone Got it, thank you! Last small question: what does the (void*) cast do?

Comment: `cout` has a special case for char* pointers, whereby it prints the string they point to rather than the address. The `void*` says `this is just a pointer, don't treat it specially`. Without it, it would print "before hello world" and "after world";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comments you indicate that your code is along the liens of:

```
char mem_arr[] = "hello world";
char* memPointer = &mem_arr[0];
memPointer += actualSize;
printf("memPointer = %p\n", &memPointer);
```

This line

```
char* memPointer = &mem_arr[0];
```

says: Let there be a variable of type `char*` called `memPointer` and let it contain *the address of the 1st element of mem_arr*. After this line, the variable `memPointer` *contains* the address of `mem_arr[0]`.

`&memPointer` expands to the *address-**of*** memPointer rather than the address that memPointer contains. memPointer is a named variable, and saying `&memPointer` evaluates to the address - location in memory - of that variable, not its value.

```
memPointer += actualSize;
printf("&mem_arr[0] = %p, memPointer = %p\n", &mem_arr[0], memPointer);
```

will set memPointer to point to the *actualSize*th element of mem_arr, as your code appears to be trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The address *of* the pointer will not change, but the pointer may point to something else if you start to increment it:

```
char* x = "test";
// *x is now 't'

x++;
// *x is now 'e'
```

There's no meaningful way to manipulate the address of the pointer itself unless you're using a pointer to a pointer, like `char** x`.

Your remark about "when the user requests some memory" and implying you must manipulate the pointer seems to be based on flawed assumptions. If you're doing this C-style you'd use `realloc()` where you get a pointer to the new allocation back. If you're doing C++ properly you'd `new` some new memory, copy the contents over, and `delete` the old allocation.

Comment: I'm implementing my own malloc. So what you're saying is that the value it holds would change, but not it's actual address? Is there any way to get the address that the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: If you're implementing your own `malloc`, which I hope is an academic exercise, read up on the full suite of allocation methods and write yours to work the same way: `malloc()`, `free()`, and `realloc()` are the most important. Follow convention unless you have a very compelling reason to diverge. Don't forget that C++ has a framework for defining [custom allocators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B)#Custom_allocators) which might be what you are trying to do here. `new` and `delete` are the C++ way, `malloc` and `free` are C.

Comment: Remember that adding something to the pointer simply changes what memory address the pointer points to, it doesn't change how much memory was allocated to that pointer, and it doesn't move the pointer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confused getting the address of *mempointer* instead of the address that *mempointer is pointing to*

This code shows how the address that my_pointer is pointing to changes whenever i increase the pointer or i give him a new memory address, take a look:

```
int mem_arr[256];
int * my_pointer = &mem_arr[0];

// let's give some values to the array just
// for fun
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    mem_arr[i] = 10 + (i * 10);
}

// print original value & address
std::cout << "Value 1: " << *my_pointer << " Address 1: " << my_pointer << std::endl;

// increase pointer (+4 bytes)
my_pointer++;

// print current value & address
std::cout << "Value 2: " << *my_pointer << " Address 2: " << my_pointer << std::endl;

// let's seek into the 8th element
// of the array
my_pointer = &mem_arr[8];

// and print current value & address once again
std::cout << "Value 3: " << *my_pointer << " Address 3: " << my_pointer << std::endl;

getchar();
```

`my_pointer`

by itself returns the address that my_pointer is pointing to, while

`&my_pointer`

returns the address where the pointer `my_pointer` is stored